# Bypass IntelliJ false errors with Stream.of

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-stream

This is a bug in the IntelliJ (16, 144.3357.4) software and I'm wondering how to temporarily bypass it while I wait for a fix. For backwards compatibility reasons, I'm building a cross-platform app that uses [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) and the [annimon](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) streams API. However, this bug is produced if I switch to Java 1.8+ and remove those packages.

**I can no longer use Stream.of**(...some Iterable...) without getting many false errors of this kind:

```
Both:
List<? extends T> in Stream and
Iterable<? extends T> in Stream match
```

I can confirm I am only ever importing the annimon Stream classes---there are no mixed imports from the Java API, and when I switch to Java 1.8+ the same holds. If I step into the source via byte-code decompilation, I do indeed see methods with the (potentially) same erasure:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> of(final List<? extends T> list)
public static <T> Stream<T> of(Iterable<? extends T> iterable)
```

Casting my objects resolves the error, but leads to un-human-parsable code and lengthy calls to `Stream.of`. I should also note this has only been an issue since the latest release. Clearly, the issue is that List also implements Iterable, so it can't decide which method I intended.

**Is there a way to resolve or suppress these errors without typecasting?**

I realize I could downgrade to an earlier version, but am wondering if there's a simpler fix.

Comment: What version of Intellij are you using?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Added.

Comment: I suupose that's an EAP; right? That could be a strong possibility. You might be able to get a progress report on the JetBrains site.

Comment: Yes I searched, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved in the update pushed this morning:

IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition) IC-144.3600.7

Build #IC-144.3600, built on February 2, 2016

Answer (score 0):

If the error is only displayed in the editor, and not when in the messages tool window when you *make* the project, you can just ignore it, your project will still build and run.

Comment: You say "you can ignore it", but it was a pervasive error over a large project, and I couldn't tell which files contained legitimate errors anymore.

Comment: Yes, it would not be very convenient. I just thought I would mention it for anybody else who has a problem like this.